# Call a function from my pc via internet

Tags: sql-server, web-services

On my PC I have a small program to run SQL Server queries and gets the results back. I don't want to duplicate the DB on the server, I want to call that program on my PC from the server (The server runs Linux OS).

I was thinking of using a web-service to communicate with my PC (using C# maybe), I can attach my PC to a Dynamic DNS (DDNS like No-IP), so I always request the name of the PC not the IP (in case the router restarted and my PC got a new IP).

What do you think, is there a better way to do that?

Answer (score 2):

The fastest solution will probably be to write a web services API written in C#/VB.NET whatever language you prefer. That API could be as simple as executing a remote ad-hoc sql query (rarely recommended) or as complex as a fully blown API. Obviously, security will be important any you may want to create your own SSL certificates and import them to your Linux server (if you're doing this on the cheap) to make sure that your home machine is the one that is reports it is!